# Flask request method changed from post to get?

Tags: python, post, get, request

I'm using flask to get information from another website,here is my code.
this is get_music.py, a function to get http://music.163.com/api/search/get/ 's music id, when I run it 
independently, it runs without problems.

```
def get_music():
baseUrl = "http://music.163.com/api/search/get/"
parameters = {
    's': "acg",
    'limit': 100,
    'type': 1
}
response = requests.post(baseUrl, data=parameters)
answer = response.json()
print(answer)
music_id = answer['result']['songs'][0]['id']
# print(music_id)
return music_id
```

But when I put it into flask, problem happen, here is my views.py code

```
@main.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
music_id = get_music()
music_id = str(music_id)

return render_template("index.html", music_id=music_id)
```

when I debug this problem, I found that the request method changed from post into get.
    when I run as a flask program, the error message say that the request method is "GET", but I'm using post method.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jkluh.png)

but when I run the `get_music.py` independently, it runs very well, 
 and the request method is post, I don't know why, can anyone else help me?

Comment: `music_id = answer['result']['songs'][0]['id']` Here I guess you are trying to get json values . There is no key called `result` in the `parameters` you pass.

Comment: yes, but it's not the point of this problem, if you run the program without flask, I can get the json values.